# How to flatten V8 ConsString?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

JavaScript V8 engine (Chrome, node) uses ConsString structures internally to represent strings that are concatenated.

The one approach to flatten this structure to a simple String that I can find mentioned online is to use `string.charCodeAt(0)`. However it seems that this no longer works (tested on Chrome 54).

Is there another way to force V8 to flatten the ConsString structure?

The way I am using these strings after creation would benefit from the flattened string (for example, reduced memory usage).

Comment: I don't know a ton about the inner workings of node, but won't creating a new `String` from your concatenated string accomplish what you want? E.g. `new String(myConcatString)`. Or does that impact performance too much?

Comment: @ChrisW - no, `new String()` does not perform the flattening. Instead it just creates a wrapper around the same internal representation as the source.

Comment: Ahh I see. I guess I have no useful input then :/

Comment: I don't think there should be a way to force the engine to use a particular internal representation, as this might easily change. What are you doing that a) you care about the internal format that much and b) that would be drastically improved by flat strings? Please post some code.

Comment: It can make a noticeable performance difference if you pass a lot of data into a write stream, like logging.

Comment: @Bergi - my case is a BI app that processes up to million rows in the browser. I do a lot of indexing upfront and there flattening helps reduce memory usage and possibly improve performance for things like `indexOf` calls.

Answer (score 3):

`Number(str)` still flattens the internal string. There's an npm module, flatstr, that does exactly that. This way your code is not full of seemingly random `Number()` calls. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatstr.

Comment: While this indeed seems to flatten the `ConsString` instances, there is also a potential drawback - in my tests it seems that if the string is internally stored as `InternalizedString`, calling `Number(str)` seems to convert it to a simple `String` or `OneByteString` so potentially increasing memory usage. So each use case has to be separately investigated if the workaround does not produce worse results.